# Bind key to specific task

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Scanning thrugh the docs this can be found:

```
{
    "key": "f4",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask"
}
```

But it only opens tasks pallete and propmts to choose a task. Question is how can I run specific task?

```
{
    "key": "f4",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask.customTask"
}
//Command not found
```

Answer (score 5):

This is documented [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_binding-keyboard-shortcuts-to-tasks). You can do this by supplying the task name via the `args` property, for instance:

```json
{
    "key": "f4",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "Run tests"
}
```

Comment: just FYI, this has to be a List, 

[
    {
        "key": "Alt+r",
        "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
        "args": "MyTask"
    },
]⏎